# Select GeoServer vector tiles feature using OpenLayers and show features attribute in popup?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles

I have installed vector tiles extension in GeoServer and published a PostGIS tables using this format. The requested vector tiles from GeoServer using Openlayers works fine. Now, I want to select and highlight a feature of a polygon layer. When I select a feature, it will be highlighted by color and then, open a popup in which show the feature attributes information. I have no idea, how can I do it?

Comment: Which format are you using to publish your vector layer? Please edit your question and add relevant part of your OpenLayers code, where you retrieve and display your layer.